# PHP validation is not what I like

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have done some javascript validation for my HTML form but I need to include some PHP validation as well, so I included the PHP validation for all the features in the HTML form when the user forget to enter something in a text input or select a radio button.

Problem is that if the user clicks on the "Prepare Question" submit button, then it doesn't display the echos when it hould do, instead it submits the form, I don't want this to happen. I don't want the form to be submitted until the php validation is met successfully. What do I need to change in my code in order for this to work:

Below is the code:

```
<form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
<p><strong>1: Your Assessment ID: </strong><span id="idFont"><?php echo $id; ?></span></p>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>' />
<p><strong>2: Number of Assessments you Require:</strong> <input type="text" id="sessionNo" name="sessionNum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" /></p>
<p><strong>3: Duration:</strong> <input type="text" id="durationpicker" name="durationChosen" readonly="readonly" /></p>
<p><strong>4: Date:</strong> <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dateChosen" readonly="readonly" /></p>
<p><strong>5: Start Time:</strong> <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="timeChosen" readonly="readonly" /><span class="timepicker_button_trigger"><img src="Images/clock.gif" alt="Choose Time" /></span></p>
<p><strong>6: </strong><input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;"/></p>      <!-- Prepare Questions here-->

</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['prequestion'])) {

if(empty($_POST['sessionNum'])) {
   echo "Please Set the Number of Assessments";
} 
elseif(empty($_POST['durationChosen'])) {
  echo "Please Select your Assessment's Duration";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['dateChosen'])) {
  echo "Please Select a Date";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['timeChosen'])) {
  echo "Please Select a Start Time";
}
else {

?>

         <script type="text/javascript">

function myClickHandler(){ 
     if(validation()){ 
                showConfirm(); 
     } 
}

<?php

}

}
?>
```

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with the fact that PHP is only executed if and when the form is submitted. You might not like that, but we can not change that. PHP therefore might not be the right technology for the job you want to solve. Thank you for the general understanding.

Comment: And with making yourself comfortable, hakre actually means _get yourself a chair, a beer (if it's legal in your country to consume at your age) and some chicken wings .._

Comment: @dbf: Please take note that the minimum age of this website is 13 years by default for the US. So the *beer* might not be appropriate. However for Jamaican users, other options are available, too.

Comment: @hakre there are actually people living in the US?

Comment: Not all, some are living in london. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjAahUKvI44

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments, I did not know this, I don't know why I am getting the down votes for this, I just asked a normal question, if I knew about php only validating after page is submitted then I wouldn't do it by php, I will just leave it to javascriot to do the validatiob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server-side scripting language so there is no straight forward way you can do a PHP validation on a form before it is submitted.

What you can do, if you have to do PHP validation for one reason or another, is to submit the field values asynchronously (in a non visible way).  You could f ex use javascript to call a GET on a hidden iframe with the form data and return errors from a separate php page (f ex calling /hidden/formcheck.php?sessionNum=XX&(...) and return false or true).

If you really want to do it in that way you'd be much better off using jQuery or some similar library who has a tonne of ready made features for remote URL calling (like jQuery's http://api.jquery.com/load/ )

Comment: It is ok, I will display an acho where if javascript is not enabled then it will display a warning at top of the page and I will just perform javascript validation

Comment: If your fear is that the JS validation won't work because JS isn't enabled for the user, you can always move the PHP validation to the top of the page you are posting to, and add a "return with error message" function.

So on your form page you will have
<?php echo $_GET['errormsg'] ?>

and on your post to page you will have
if (isset($_POST['prequestion']))
(...)
and if those fails you do:
header("Location: http://www.example.com/form.php?errormsg=thisdidntwork")